# IIS Tag Pool Idle Time-out Max Value Behavior?

Tags: iis

We had a web-application on Windows Sever 2012 that was taking a while to load up on Monday. I found that in the App Pool that Advanced Settings->Idle Time-out (minutes) was set to 1440, to terminate after 24 hours of non-use. To stop it from timing out after over the weekend, I upped it to 10080 for 7 days of non-use.

2 hours later the App Pool restarted. It has never done this before, so while it makes no sense, I am looking into why changing this setting could have caused this.

I'm looking for general information, but mostly if there is a max value I am exceeding with this.

Comment: Did you enable `logEventOnRecyle` and confirm that this restart after 2 hours was caused by `ConfigChange`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/#attributes

Comment: The default value of the idle timeout in IIS is 20 minutes, which can be adjusted according to the requirements of the application. There is no maximum limit to the idle timeout value, but setting an "idle timeout" that is too long may result in increased resource consumption. Increasing the "idle timeout" setting should not directly cause the pool to restart, there could be other underlying issues or misconfigurations. It is recommended that you check the Windows Event Viewer logs for any related events or error messages around the time when the application pool restarted.

Comment: I do have logEventsOnRecycle enabled, checking the EventViewer I found: `The worker processes serving application pool are being recycled due to 1 or more configuration changes in the application pool properties which necessitate a restart of the processes.` This happened 10 minutes after I made the configuration change. All I changed was Idle Time-out. For whatever reason, the program continued for a couple hours, before the whole thing restarted in the middle of a user doing a routine task when there was no inactivity. I'll look into this more on the weekend as I cant have this happen.

Comment: Debug Diagnostics Tool (DebugDiag)  maybe can be a lifesaver. It creates and analyze IIS crash dumps. When you see the call stack, you may be able to find the cause of the crash.
IIS Application Pool Crash and Debug Diag
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/parvez/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag

Answer (score 0):

> The worker processes serving application pool ' [Application pool
> name] ' are being recycled due to 1 or more configuration changes in
> the application pool properties which necessitate a restart of the
> processes.

Have you ever read about application pool gets recycled due to anti-virus?

For example, when anti-virus scans the concerned file, it changed the "Last modification time"; It can also occur when WAS tries to detect if the configuration file has been changed, while anti-virus is scanning the file at the same time hence WAS detects the handle on the file and considers it being modified. One effective way to avoid this scenario is by excluding the related configuration files of IIS from the anti-virus scanning scope.

I'm not sure if you are in the same situation, more details you can go through this link to know: [Application pool gets recycled due to anti-virus?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/application-pool-gets-recycled-due-to-anti-virus/ba-p/826673)